# In python3, how do I properly force my program to move through a loop before it has finished playing a song?

Tags: subprocess, python-3.6, speech-recognition, ubuntu-18.04, keyboardinterrupt

I'm writing a virtual assistant in python3.  I have a while loop that plays two randomly selected songs.  I press ctrl c to skip to the next song. Here's the part of a long, long if statement.  Once the songs start, I can go to the next song by hitting ctrl c, but then after the last song ends, the program gets stuck.  I need to hit ctrl c again for it to move on.  BTW, When music is playing the microphone stops working, which is fine, but that means I can't yell "stop" or "next," so a key press seems best.

```
# next command
    elif 'music' in command:
        if playcounter == 1:
            talktome.talkToMe("Choosing random song . . . ")
        with open('/home/bard/Code/Juliet/mymusiclist.txt') as f:
            if playcounter == 1:
                print("Total songs to play " + str(totalsongstoplay) + ".")
            mymusic = f.read().splitlines()
            random_index = randrange(len(mymusic))
            song = mymusic[random_index]
            print("Playing song number " + str(playcounter) + ".")
            print("Song file:")
            print(song)
            playthis = 'mpg123 -q ' + song
            #subprocess.call(playthis, shell=True)
            p1=subprocess.Popen(playthis, shell=True)
            try:
                #while True:
                while p1.poll is not None:
                    pass
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                # Ctrl-C was pressed (or user knew how to send SIGTERM to the python process)
                pass # not doing anything here, just needed to get out of the loop
            # nicely ask the subprocess to stop
            p1.terminate()
            # read final output
            sleep(1)
            # check if still alive
            if p1.poll() is not None:
                print('had to kill it')
                p1.kill()
            #end new code
            if playcounter < totalsongstoplay:
                playcounter = playcounter + 1
                assistant(command, playcounter, totalsongstoplay)
            else:
                playcounter=1
# next command
```

Thank you. The full project is at https://github.com/MikeyBeez/Juliet  BTW, this voice activated assistant does all its speech to text locally -- nothing in the cloud.  I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, and I use Conda for my virtual environment.  Python is 3.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it:

```
# next command
    elif 'music' in command:
        if playcounter == 1:
            talktome.talkToMe("Choosing random song . . . ")
        with open('/home/bard/Code/Juliet/mymusiclist.txt') as f:
            if playcounter == 1:
                print("Total songs to play " + str(totalsongstoplay) + ".")
            mymusic = f.read().splitlines()
            random_index = randrange(len(mymusic))
            song = mymusic[random_index]
            print("Playing song number " + str(playcounter) + ".")
            print("Song file:")
            print(song)
            playthis = 'mpg123 -q ' + song
            p1=subprocess.Popen(playthis, shell=True)
            try:
                #while True:
                while p1.poll() is None:
                    pass
                #p1.wait()
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                # Ctrl-C was pressed (or user knew how to send SIGTERM to the python process)
                pass # not doing anything here, just needed to get out of the loop
            # nicely ask the subprocess to stop
            p1.terminate()
            # read final output
            sleep(1)
            # check if still alive
            if p1.poll() is not None:
                print('had to kill it')
                p1.kill()
            #end new code
            if playcounter < totalsongstoplay:
                playcounter = playcounter + 1
                assistant(command, playcounter, totalsongstoplay)
            #end if 
            playcounter = 1
```